# Reassigning chars in a char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to terminate a string early based on some arbitrary condition, by doing this:

```
void end_string_early(char string[], int len) {
    int i;
    char j;

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        j = string[i];                                   
        if (arbitrary_condition(j)) {
            string[i] = "a";
        }
    }
}
```

I get the compile error:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

What confuses me, is if I do the exact same thing with an int array (changing the value to be another int, instead of a) then it works perfectly. Perhaps it's something with how the argument is being passed? (Though I was under the impression all arrays were passed by ref) I'm not entirely sure and this is my first go at C (working through K&R book).

Comment: `"a"` is an array (of length 2) which *decays* to a pointer before the assignment. You want `'a'` (an `int` that can be interpreted as a `char`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'a'` and `"a"` are two different things: the first is the *character a*, the second is a literal string containing only the character *a*.

You're trying to assign a literal string to a character. `"a"` is a literal string, i.e. a `char *`, and an element of your `char[]` is a `char`: an integral type, hence the message about trying to assign a pointer to an integer. The message is a bit confusing because `char` is an integral type.

So use:

```
string[i] = 'a';
```

But this doesn't terminate the string. For that you'll need:

```
string[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[i] = "a";
```

must be

```
string[i] = 'a';
```

Note the different quotes.

---

`string` is an array from `char`s, and `"a"` is *not* a `char`, it's string literal, containing two `char`s - one for `a` and one `\0`.
So, to set a `char` element into a `char` array, you need to use single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 1):

`"a"` is a `char[2]`, which decays to a `char*` and that's why you're getting that warning; `string` is a `char*` so `string[i]` is a `char` which means you are trying to assign a `char*` to a `char`, which is wrong.

You need to use single quotes:

```
string[i] = 'a';
```

Double quotes make an array of `char` and single quotes make just a single `char`, so `'a'` is a `char` and assigning a `char` to a `char` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will work better with `string[i] = 'a';` (instead of `"a"`).

Just in case, be aware that [it's not possible to re-assign the chars of a literal string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string). The piece of code you show does not have this problem, but if you called `end_string_early("foo"...)`, it would.

Answer (score 1):

`"a"` is not a char -- it's a `char*` (string). You need `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

`string[i] = "a"` should be `string[i] = 'a'`, `"a"` is different from `'a'`, where "a" is a literal string and it "returns a pointer, while `'a'` is just a char.